# hciconfig Features hex codes

Tags: command-line, bluetooth

I can't seem to find anywhere what the hex codes listed under hciconfig Features stand for.  Does anyone know where I can find a list to show which feature corresponds to which hex code?

```
Output:
$ hciconfig -a hci0 features
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:0E:8E:49:38:9D  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
    Features page 0: 0xff 0xfb 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
            <3-slot packets> <5-slot packets> <encryption> <slot offset> 
            <timing accuracy> <role switch> <hold mode> <sniff mode> 
            <park state> <RSSI> <SCO link> <HV2 packets> <HV3 packets> 
            <u-law log> <A-law log> <CVSD> <paging scheme> <power control> 
            <transparent SCO> <broadcast encrypt> <EDR ACL 2 Mbps> 
            <EDR ACL 3 Mbps> <enhanced iscan> <interlaced iscan> 
            <interlaced pscan> <inquiry with RSSI> <extended SCO> 
            <EV4 packets> <EV5 packets> <AFH cap. slave> 
            <AFH class. slave> <LE support> <3-slot EDR ACL> 
            <5-slot EDR ACL> <sniff subrating> <pause encryption> 
            <AFH cap. master> <AFH class. master> <EDR eSCO 2 Mbps> 
            <EDR eSCO 3 Mbps> <3-slot EDR eSCO> <extended inquiry> 
            <LE and BR/EDR> <simple pairing> <encapsulated PDU> 
            <err. data report> <non-flush flag> <LSTO> <inquiry TX power> 
            <EPC> <extended features> 
    Features page 1: 0x07 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

Answer (score 0):

As in this: http://exploiterz.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-anonymize-bluetooth-devices-on.html

hci0 or hci(x) is the name of your Bluetooth device and you can get all available devices using the command: `$ hciconfig`, but if you select one of them you can use: `hciconfig -a hcix` to see its info, and as well its futures using the command you typed here in your question `$ hciconfig hci0 features` which shows all features supported by your bluetooth device.

if you want to know for example what is the meaning of   "3-slot packets" or "interlaced pscan" these are futures supported by the device but to know the details of these futures there is a forum for Bluetooth developers: https://developer.bluetooth.org/Pages/default.aspx

it will give you more details.